# VB.NET hates </script> tag in string literal

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to update some of my projects old login code, which is a bunch of aspx files with inline VB.NET (no codebehind).

The page in question uses a master page layout. I am trying to expose the header of this master page to the slave pages, which I did by adding a placeholder in the header and exposing it as a property of the master page.

The problem comes in when I try to add a script tag to the header, like this:

```
Master.Header.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mysite.com/myscript.ashx'></script>"))
```

Then i get the error "Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls."

I think the aspx parser is seeing the `</script>` in the string literal and thinking that it is then end of the  tag, and giving me that error because it thinks the content following that end tag are not in an  block. I can add other tags to the header perfectly fine.

What do you think?

Comment: Just a guess, try double-quotes around the attribute(s): `"<script src=""http://mysite.com/myscript.ashx""></script>"` or HTML encoding: `"&lt;script src='http://mysite.com/myscript.ashx'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape the `/` in `</script>` to prevent this.

```
Master.Header.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mysite.com/myscript.ashx'><\/script>"))
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked! I'll accept in 9 minutes. 

Is this a generic .aspx parser thing or a vb.net thing? I have always used code-behind myself.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try

```
Dim gc As New HtmlGenericControl
gc.TagNane = "script"
gc.Attributes.Add("type", "javascript")
gc.Attributes.Add("src", "http://mysite.com/myscript.ashx")
Master.Header.Controls.Add(gc)
```