# Literal "</select>" Error In ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-3.5

Why does my the declaration of my string in the code result in the following error?  Is there a workaround?

Code:

```
<script runat="server">

Protected Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim x As String = "</script>"
    Response.Write(x) 
End Sub
</script>
```

Error: Statement cannot appear within a method body. End of method assumed.

Note: The following page did not fix my issue and instead resulted in the string `<\/script>` being output in my page. ( [VB.NET hates </script> tag in string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472277/vb-net-hates-script-tag-in-string-literal) )

Comment: `resulted in the string "</script>" being output in my page` What is your expectation from this snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
<script runat="server">
Protected Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim x As String = "</" + "script>"
    Response.Write(x) 
End Sub
</script>
```